# Using Rails 2.3.8 I am trying to create a new view for a child object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a pretty basic issue I guess.  I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rail 2.3.8 b/c the web host is pretty out of date.  Anyways,  I have an Event which has RSVPs associated with it. I have an administrator that I want to have access to a better view (more information_ of the RSVPs for the event.

The RSVP currently indexes like normal `/events/1/rsvps` which I get to using `event_rsvps_path(event)` and use an `index.html.erb` file.  I made a `adminindex.html.erb` and put an `adminindex` in the `rsvp` controller.  But now I don't know how to create a link to that `adminindex.html.erb` file.

The usual methods like `link_to :controller=>'rsvps', :action=>'adminindex'` don't work for obvious reasons to me.

The Routes file has `map.resources :rsvps, :except => :update`

Can someone tell me how to link the index to the adminindex file if the admin is signed in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `routes.rb` file. Creating a resource only makes routes for the 7 RESTful actions (index, show, new, create, edit, update, destroy)

Since you have a custom action, you have to add a custom route for it. Try this:

```
map.resources :rsvps, :except => :update, :collection => { :adminindex => :get }
```

Run `rake routes` to see if it made the route correctly.